# How do I make this brighter?

Tags: lighting

How can I make the water brighter? I have fiddled with lots of different sliders and got nothing. Adding more lamps results in the whole render being too bright(This is my first low poly isometric render and it is incomplete).[image]

Comment: if you really can't make it brighter you could use an Emission shader

Comment: _One_ of the things that looks to be affecting the apparent brightness of the sea is that the entire scene is bathed in a light of a roughly complementary color, by the World. There's not much blue-green around for the sea to reflect, diffusely. Try changing the dominant light color.. ( it doesn't have to wind up being the color you actually see in the background)

Comment: Unfortunately that is a plane, not the world so its not emitting any light. The sea already has a glass shader to create water. I also need to get those two front faces lit up somehow : /